# Pass custom query strings across website

Tags: uri

I want to use some custom query strings for tracking purposes and for visibility rules. The goal is, to provide a link such as www.example.com#affiliateid=1 and the string is preserved through the whole web session. Ideally, # should be used instead of ?, as it is ignored by google and prevents duplicate content.

However, each time I click a link on my site, the parameters are lost.

I don't really know where to start -
are they usually passed and is this a problem with url rewrite or would I have to learn drupal that it should append the strings to each link?

Thank you!

Comment: I found a working jQuery-based solution on the internet (see answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working jQuery-based Solution on the Internet:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var persistedQueryParam = getParameterByName('PARAMETER1');

if (persistedQueryParam && persistedQueryParam.length > 0) {
$('a[href]').each(function () {
  var elem = $(this);
  var href = elem.attr('href');
  elem.attr('href', href + (href.indexOf('?') != -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'PARAMETER1=' + persistedQueryParam);
});
}
});
```

This seems to work good SEO wise as the links seem to stay the same until click. So I suppose google should be ale to use the original rel=canonical link, right? Or would I have to write an exception for it?

Comment: So I checked it with Google Webmaster Tools and it is safe SEO-wise!

Only problem that occurs is that it breaks html anchors as the query string is appended a second time once anchor link is clicked.

Comment: I figured out a solution: problem was, that html anchors are also inside href. I solved the problem via excluding links beginning with #:

    $('a[href]').not('a[href^="#"]').each

Answer (score 0):

That's probably a bit messy. Have you considered using cookies or even the session variable?

**Edit:**
Turns out it might actually be possible and without much fuss! Thanks OP for raising the question and making us question (and research) this a bit.

Drupal has a hook to rewrite all URLs (hook_url_outbound_alter), which coming to think about it makes total sense.

Basically you can use this hook to grab a session variable or a cookie - you still want to store it somewhere just so that in case you lose it at some point you can easily retrieve it and recover the navigation - and rewrite the URLs according to whatever rules you need.

Here's a sample for future reference, not mine just adding it here so we don't lose it if the link breaks:

```
<?php
/* Helper function for using strpos with an array of strings.
 */

function strposa ($haystack, $needles) {
    $bool = false;
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            $bool = true;
        }
    }
    return $bool;
}

/* Implements hook_url_outbound_alter
 */

function rl_int_url_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) { 
    //Break path into an array
    $arr = explode('/',$path);
    //Get country list and exclude paths
    $c_list = array('us','ca');
    $system_paths = array('admin', 'user', 'sites', 'system');
    $exclude_paths = array('node/add', 'sitemap');
    //If the path contains a system path in the first argument, or has an exclude path in the full path string, do not set a prefix.
    if (in_array($arr[0], $system_paths) || strposa($path, $exclude_paths)) {
        $options['prefix'] = '' ;
    //OK, it's not an excluded path. If the path doesn't have the prefix already, add a prefix.
    } else if (in_array($arr[0], $c_list) == false) {
        $c = $_COOKIE('Drupal_visitor_country');
        $l = $_COOKIE('Drupal_visitor_language');
        $options['prefix'] = $c . '/' . $l . '/';
        //Special case: remove "home" from the path if it's the home page, so that it's example.com/us/en instead of example.com/us/en/home.
        if (drupal_lookup_path('alias', $path) === 'home') {
            $path = '';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Agree with the @FreeRadical's comment, but this it *is* messy to carry the URL fragment from page to page, specially because the server does not receive that. The question should be posted in SO probably/

Comment: I know it probably is a bit messy, but so far the best solution that came to my mind for various reasons:

Comment: Goal is to use it for a.) a partner program with a different header displayed for visitors using certain parameters and b.) an affiliate program, for wich I want to track clicks and actions of users seperately.


On the technical side using URL strings would provide:

1. easy tracking with Google Analytics
2. most important: my site relies on BOOST module. A different cache has to be built for anonymous users using the link with the query string. Not sure if I can use cookies for this.

Comment: Deleted my initial (critical) comment. Answer is much improved.